# Fixed vs adjustable DC-DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

When choosing a DC-DC converter like the LM2596, does it matter if the output voltage is fixed or adjustable?

Until now, if I need a fixed 5V output, I've chosen to do it using a constant 5V regulator. I did this not to use fewer components, but because I thought it would be more stable. Is this correct or is it a superstition? If we are operating at a constant voltage, are there valid reasons to prefer either one?

Comment: A fixed regulator is pretty much the same circuit as an adjustable regulator but the adjustment isn't something you can change. One advantage is you can't accidentally adjust it!

Comment: @user253751 Conversely, the disadvantage is you can't adjust it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use adjustable regulators you can get whatever voltage you want. For example, you might want some odd voltage to feed into an LDO for a low-noise analog supply (high enough to be well away from dropout and where PSRR is high).

You can also stock only one regulator type instead of a different part number for every voltage. Since there are literally thousands of LDO and switching voltage regulators available this could help a bit.

That said, there are a lot of cases where 5.0, 3.3 and 1.8 are necessary and maybe even sufficient.

Your main question is whether it is more **stable**. You'd have to read the datasheet to determine that. Probably it won't make a lot of difference- the on-chip voltage divider will use matched and thermally close resistors so the ratio should be relatively stable. You could degrade it with your external resistors if you use less stable or matched resistors (eg. a carbon film resistor for one and a metal film for the other). But usually for something like a LM2596 the on-chip reference tolerance and tempco will be more limiting (but it depends on what they guarantee, as we will see).

Let's take a look at the original (NS/TI) [LM2596](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2595.pdf) (not the many clones etc.)

[image]

So we have an iron-clad guarantee of output voltage 5.0V +/-5% over the full temperature range and a range of input voltage and load. Pretty sweet, well maybe not the 100mA minimum load, but still good.

[image]

Okay, so here we have a guarantee of the feedback voltage which we can translate into output voltage via the resistor ratio (and the feedback bias current which is typically low but could be +/-100nA).

The tolerance on the feedback voltage **alone** over temperature is +/-5% which means that you'll have a worst-case tolerance that is always worse than using the fixed voltage regulator, since any resistor pair has some tolerance. Using +/-1% resistors, the worst-case error due to the resistors for a 5V output will be about +/-1.5%, plus some error if you use two E96 series resistors since you won't likely find values that exactly match the required ratio, plus some error due to bias current. So worst-case error is probably closer to +/-6.5~7% than +/-5%. Temperature drift similarly will be worse. A 100ppm/°C 1% resistor could drift 1% for 100°C change so, in theory anyway, you could see another 1.5% over temperature, making the error more than +/-8%.

Comment: I'm not worried about stock 'for now'. The issue of tolerance interests me more. This is why I tend to use fixed voltage. But I will add the ADJ circuit to the pcb design, because of  in order not to enter a new pcb production process when I change my mind (maybe another regulator).

Comment: So you replace one resistor with 0\$\Omega\$ when you use a fixed voltage regulator. That's good strategy in these times.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for adjustable:

1. More control over filtering of feedback signal
2. Depending on the level of integration of the switcher, some may not allow regulation at the point of load via a kelvin connection. Some fixed regulators have the feedback internally so can only regulate the voltage at their output pin which is different than the point of load due to trace resistance.